# GAE External Email Service API

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I am looking for an Email Server/Service (preferably something decent thats not probable to shut down any time soon) that I can use in my GAE application. 
Here is the situation
I have an application in which users will sign up and register and use the app, pretty straight forward, however, my app involves sending messages from the system administration to clients, in the form of notifications, also will send important content like invoices consents, attendance confirmation, and what not (bottom line, not marketing content that I can send to email database) they will get a copy as well for reference in their emails, but thats for the sort of things that are important to document.

I need advice if there is any Emailing service, that would allow me (using api) to create an email account for each user that signs up, which I can send system notifications to, and then provide api for loading messages to the user through a browser or mobile app.

Last XMPP and Push for real time notification delivery would be fantastic !!
Pretty much I cant start my own on site server for financial reasons and because this is not a demo project, this is going to production, so client specification requires all to be in the cloud.

One last thing, the whole process has to be through api, the user will not even be aware that there is a new email for him and that we are sending emails, as far as he is concerned its just like Facebook notifications and inbox messages.

(obviously it can be done on Google through corporate account, but it would be great it I can get a free alternative)

Any constructive criticism on my approach towards the subject will be very much appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to send email from a GAE application or are you trying to replicate an email system that you want to host in your GAE application?

Comment: Neither ... I want the user to be unaware that there is an email system involved. Take stackoverflow ... you signed up, and you got an inbox on the website GUI, which is different than the email inbox you used to sign in ... technically I can manage that inbox on the datastore, but it would be orders of magnitude easier if I make the application sign up for an email account on some 3rd party server USING API (user not involved here) then save that address to datastore. Anytime i need to communicate with user i send to that address

Comment: The reason for all of this later when the user logs in my application, his user name and password will be loaded to be used by a ajax to load his messages using the api. The messages can be easily sorted to read and unread,and can contain attachments. Other advantages like datastore space and quotas and traffic and whatnot are obvious at that point ..  Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you think it would be easier to make your application sign up for an email account on some 3rd party server via API.  But I suspect that is going to be harder.  I've never heard of an email system exposed by API.  So it may be hard to find one.  Maybe try searching for Inbox API (here's a weak lead https://stackapps.com/questions/3184/are-there-any-plans-to-add-inbox-functionality-to-so-api).  I'd be inclined to design something from scratch.